# How can I switch the database context of an existing DataSource?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, datasource

Let's say I have an existing DataSource to a master database. I now need to create a new database, and execute some DDLs on that database. Is this possible with e.g, "USE" command, or do I need to create a new DataSource with the name of the new database in the JDBC url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USE statement works, but since it's stateful, you have to make sure that it's part of the same connection as the latter statements.

If you use Spring's `JdbcTemplate` instead of working with `java.sql.Connection` and `java.sql.Statement` directly, you can use a `SingleConnectionDataSource`.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the "USE" command as a regular JDBC statement.

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.execute("USE the_other_db");
```

Dependending on your DBMS and driver you might also be able to use the JDBC API call setCatalog():

```
connection.setCatalog("the_other_db")
```